# How do you write jquery to fade out all items of a certain type all the time

Tags: jquery

So ... I know how to fadeout an item added to the dom (A success/error message in this case), but the way I'm doing it now is by writing the code to fadeout the specific item I need when it is loaded with the DOM, but also writing seperate fadeOut code when the item is added via AJAX.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this?
I looked into using the .live() handler but that requires an event be passed in as one of its parameters (not good because I just want the item to fade out after a set amount of time, no matter what).

tldr; I'm trying to write a piece of code that will fadeOut an item whether it loads with the DOM or is added to it (via AJAX for example).

Comment: I'm trying to understand what triggers the fade out...

Comment: You want a selector that will know if the dom element was rendered by source html or added after initial render ? hmmm

Comment: @TJB ... think about the .live() call in jquery and how that works ... thats what I want to do for these items

Comment: @superfro I don't need it to know any of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [livequery plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs).

```
$(".fadeOut").livequery(function(){$(this).fadeOut()});
```

Comment: This looks like it might be what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

when you add the divs to the dom, assign a class for e.g

```
<div ...class="your_usual_class fadeout_category other_classes"...>
```

So now all objects that belong to the fadeout_category can be easily faded with a command

$(".fadeout_category").apply_fadeout;

Comment: I don't want to make a separate call to fade out this item, I want it to fade out automatically like it would if I had used .live() ... only .live() requires an event type as one of its parameters

Answer (score -1):

The most "elegant" solution to your problem would not be to use `.live`, which listens to a particular DOM node for changes (always use a context for your selector; the callbacks can slow down a complicated page substantially) and then just applies a normal callback assuming the selector conditions are met.

You would want to include the fadeOut with the function that makes the item appear in the first place.

```
namespace.showMessage = function(message) {
  $('<div class="message">').text(message).appendTo('body').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing now and don't want to do any more.

Comment: In that case, livequery is what you want, but I would recommend against it. I've used livequery on numerous occasions myself, and in each case, I ended up refactoring to remove it because it was too difficult to keep track of all the livequeries going on. Best of luck in your application.